# Javascript Regex as a string not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to understand why writing regex as a string is not working but using it without string does work.

this is my example:

```
var patt = new RegExp("/test_.*/gi");
var res = patt.test("test_4");
console.log(res);
```

will return false

but this:

```
var patt = /test_.*/gi;
var res = patt.test("test_4");
console.log(res);
```

will return true

what is the difference

Comment: see constructor call : [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Although not related to the problem here (since it hasn't manifested), don't use `g` flag with `test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax of [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) is wrong.

1. The delimiters are not required when you use `RegExp` constructor to create new Regular Expression.
2. The flags should be passed as second parameter to the `RegExp` constructor.
3. And `.` should to be escaped, if you want to match `.` literal.

**Usage**

```
var patt = new RegExp("test_.*", "gi");
```

**Demo**

```js
var patt = new RegExp("test_.*", "gi");
var res = patt.test("test_4");
document.write(res);
```

Comment: @lobengula3rd Check updated answer. I've also included `Demo`

Comment: why escape the `.` ? not the same Regex as OP.

Comment: Do not write `"\."` in string. While it technically works, since the `\.` resolves into `.` in the string literal before going into RegExp constructor, it is confusing to the reader

Comment: @Hacketo I thought OP wants to match `.` literal, Thanks for clarification, I've updated answer

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks! I've updated answer

Answer (score 1):

The regexp constructor does not need delimiters, also, flags are isolated in another argument which simplifies it to

```
var patt = new RegExp('test_.*', 'gi');
var res = patt.test("test_4");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to include the `/` at the start and end of the regular expression when using the constructor and the flags need to be in the second argument. See the [MDN Documentation for RegExp.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```js
var patt = new RegExp( "test_.*", "gi" );
var res = patt.test("test_4");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the constructor correctly, the falgs should be passed as a second parameter:

```
new RegExp('test_.*', 'gi');
```

As you can see in **[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)**, it should respect this format:

```
new RegExp(pattern[, flags])
```

This is your demo:

```js
var patt = new RegExp("test_.*", 'gi');
var res = patt.test("test_4");
alert(res);
```